# The type or namespace name 'routing' does not exist in the namespace 'system.web' visual studio

Tags: c#, web-reference, system.web, system.web.routing

> The type or namespace name 'Routing' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I added web reference System.Web.Routing, but still it showing error.

[image]

Comment: What is your .NET Framework version?

Comment: As @SonerGönül say, it requires Ver3.5 or later.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: i am using 3.5 version......visual studio 2008

Comment: are you add reference to dll with this namespace?

Comment: i did not add any dll file .........but i added web reference "system.web."...any dll file for web routing is not exist in bin folder...

Comment: You want to add a normal reference, not a web reference.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have .NET 3.5 with SP1.

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tydxdyw9%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> To simplify development of XML Web service client applications, Visual
>   Studio provides Web references. Web references differ from traditional
>   references and components; instead of referencing a component or a
>   class library installed on the local computer, a Web reference
>   provides access to a resource that is available using an Internet
>   protocol such as SOAP or HTTP. In practice, a Web reference is a
>   generated proxy class that locally represents the exposed
>   functionality of an XML Web service.

A web reference isn't what you want - in simple terms, references allow you to call into DLLs, while web references are used to call web services.

Remove the 'web reference' you've made, and add a normal reference instead.